# Perl hash giving strict refs error

Tags: perl, hash, ref

I am trying to write code to add up revenue on sales based on the month of a particular year and output total per month per year, something with my code is wrong though and I am just stuck now.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my @newPlans = `cat plansSold.txt`;
my @oldPlans = `cat plansCancelled.txt`;
my %amounts;
for(@newPlans){
    chomp;
    my ($price,$billPeriod,$date) = (split /\;/, $_ )[4,5,7];
    my $montly = $price/$billPeriod;
    my ($f,$l) = (split /\-/, $date)[0,1];
    $montly = (split /\./, $montly)[0];
    $date = "$f\-$l";
    $amounts{$date} += $montly;
}
for my $date (sort keys %amounts) {
    print '.';
    print "$amounts{$date} : $_\n" for (sort keys %{ $amounts{$date} });
}
```

$price,$billPeriod,$date Are as below.

```
7.95,1,2012-04
9.95,1,2012-06
19.95,12,2012-06
19.95,1,2014-02
12.95,3,2013-03
19.95,1,2014-01
18.95,1,2012-12
18.95,6,2012-12
18.95,1,2012-05
```

And the error:

```
Can't use string ("6177") as a HASH ref while "strict refs" in use at revenueHistory.pl line 28.
```

Whis is this line

```
for my $date (sort keys %amounts) {
```

I cant seem to figure out how to fix it.

Comment: Please don't shell out to a new process just to read the contents of a file

Comment: Please show the contents of your input files

Comment: Is this a program that you've inherited from someone else? If so then you should say so. That way you would avoid a lot of the flack that the original author deserved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line

```
print "$amounts{$date} : $_\n" for (sort keys %{ $amounts{$date} });
```

is trying to treat a numeric total in `$amounts{$date}` as a hash reference, and it isn't.  You've been totaling up a running total, and you have a number, but now you want it to be a hash reference, and that doesn't make sense.

What is it you're actually trying to do?

Comment: Basically it should print out

    2013-01 : $10000
    2013-02 : $1500

    And so on.

Comment: So why don't you just print that? `print "$date : $amounts{$date}\n"`

Comment: I tried that but I think my math has an issue or something because I am not getting the correct values.

Answer (score -2):

Got it

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my @newPlans = `cat plansSold.txt`;
my @oldPlans = `cat plansCancelled.txt`;
my %amounts;
my $hold = 'tt';
for(@newPlans){
    chomp;
    my ($price,$billPeriod,$date) = (split /\;/, $_ )[4,5,7];
    my $montly = $price/$billPeriod;
    my ($f,$l) = (split /\-/, $date)[0,1];
    $montly = (split /\./, $montly)[0];
    $date = "$f\-$l";
    $amounts{$date}{$date} += $montly;
    #print "$price,$billPeriod,$date\n";
}
for my $date (sort keys %amounts) {
    print '.';
    print "$amounts{$date}{$date} : $_\n" for (sort keys %{ $amounts{$date}});
}
```

Comment: That did not fix your code, you just added another error to cancel out your first error. What is wrong with `sort keys %amounts`? And do you really need to loop twice?

Comment: Also... even if it had fixed your code, this is just a blind dump of code. Don't forget there are newbies on this site that would like to know how your change would have fixed it... a bit more explanation is always a good thing :)

Comment: @ThatGuy: Please show the contents of your input files

Comment: Yea, I got this bit from another guy to be honest. I used it for something a little different and modification isn't working. The contents of the input file are above in the original post, essentially it is a price,billingperiod,date...I want the monthly dollar amount from each row, so if a price is 1200 the value is 120. I then want to take every dollar amount and add it up based on the month. So 2014-01 will show as 2014-01 : $totalDollars. It seems to be adding wrong though as excel shows a different value than the script is spitting out.